# Imputing small region of the genome

Tags: snp, imputation, haplotypes, tools

If I'm looking for a specific SNP in my SNP-Chip data and it isn't there, are there any tools that let me quickly impute that SNP from surrounding SNPs rather than running a lengthy 'whole chromosome' imputation job?

If so, roughly how many upstream and downstream SNPs are generally required to predict the haploblock 'accurately'?

Answer (score 3):

I would take something like 1.5Mb either side of the SNP of interest (so a 3Mb chunk), subset that out from the target and reference panel and then perform imputation on that chunk alone. I think that size will give you more than enough LD, [since LD decays by about 500kB in most human populations by then.](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4425/8/5/133/htm)

[shapeit4 has an option to just impute a single region](https://odelaneau.github.io/shapeit4/#documentation):

```
shapeit4 \
    --input unphased.bcf \
    --map chr20.b37.gmap.gz \
    --region chr21:1231213-1413143 \ ## change this bit
    --reference reference.bcf \
    --output phased.bcf
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clear enough. I'm just looking for a tool to make that easy for me ;-)

Comment: @dan see edit, shapeit4 can impute just a particular region